# Can I use an image insted of text in an accordion panel with collapse functionality?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Like I said, I am trying to replace the heading of an accordion panel with an image. If i set class="panel-collapse collapse in" the text is shown. However when I remove "in" and try to click the image to drop down the text is not shown.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" href="#body">
            <img src="../img/penguinsPhotograph.png" alt="Penguins Photograph" class="img-responsive"/>
          </a>   
      </div>
      <div id="body" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>
             This is random text. Just for testing.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--end accordion -->
```

Comment: May I ask why this was down voted?

Comment: Oh it appears that something is going on with the bootstrap I was using. I checked out a new version and it works. In case someone wonders.